# Accessing c# ServiceController Local value StartType

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ServiceConroller object than has a value for StartType that I can see when I view locals in debug mode, but the dll does not have a definition for this property. How can I access this property?

I have tried different version of the System.ServiceProcess.ddl but the property is not defined. However it is listed in the class definitions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruev2.png)

Comment: Which version of .Net are you running? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.starttype(v=vs.110).aspx it's only available since 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

That property is available since 4.6.1 [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.starttype(v=vs.110).aspx). Target that framework version.

Comment: I thought I had the latest version but obviously not. I will download now. Thanks for help.